# Redirect 301 - try to redirect links from old page asp to new page php

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess, redirect

I try to redirect my old link who stand good on Google to my new php site. I try with `Redirect 301` but no luck, try with and without site domain but no luck. All way lead me to starting page. I don't know is it a problem because old page was on .asp? http://www.dalmaturist.hr/

```
      Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^hrv/ponuda/izleti.asp /hr/izleti [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^hrv/kontakti/karta.asp /hr/pakostane [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^eng/offer/excursions.asp /en/excursions [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^hrv/o_nama/index.asp /hr/najam-plovila/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^hrv/ponuda/rent.asp /hr/najam-plovila/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mjesto=1$
RewriteRule ^itravel/hrv/rezultati.asp$ /hr/smjestaj/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mjesto=1&stranica=6$
RewriteRule ^itravel/deu/rezultati.asp$  /de/unterkunft/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mjesto=1&stranica=2$
RewriteRule ^itravel/eng/rezultati.asp$ /en/accommodation/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sifra_apartmana=12&view_date=01/6/2014$
RewriteRule ^itravel/deu/detalji.asp$ /de/bootscharter/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sifra_apartmana=84&view_date=01/6/2013$
RewriteRule ^itravel/eng/detalji.asp$ /en/accommodation/? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^hr$ /index.php?lang=hr
RewriteRule ^en$ /index.php?lang=en
RewriteRule ^de$ /index.php?lang=de

## Hrvatski ##

RewriteRule ^hr/dalmaturist$ /dalmaturist.php
RewriteRule ^hr/placanja$ /placanja.php
RewriteRule ^hr/uvjeti$ /uvjeti.php
RewriteRule ^hr/smjestaj/(.*)$ /smjestaj.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^hr/smjestaj_sortiranje$ /smjestaj_sortiranje.php
RewriteRule ^hr/objekt/(.*)/(.*)$ /smjestaj-objekt.php?SmjestajID=$1&SmjestajSeo=$2
RewriteRule ^hr/najam-plovila/(.*)$ /rent-boat.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^hr/rent-boat_sortiranje$ /rent-boat_sortiranje.php
RewriteRule ^hr/brod/(.*)/(.*)$ /rent-boat-objekt.php?PloviloID=$1&PloviloSeo=$2
RewriteRule ^hr/izleti$ /izleti.php
RewriteRule ^hr/suvenirnica$ /suvenirnica.php
RewriteRule ^hr/pakostane$ /pakostane.php
RewriteRule ^hr/okruzenje$ /okruzenje.php
RewriteRule ^hr/kontakt$ /kontakt.php
RewriteRule ^hr/bicikli-skuteri$ /bike-scooter.php
RewriteRule ^hr/rezervacija$ /rezervacija.php
RewriteRule ^hr/thank-you$ /thank-you.php

## Engleski ##

RewriteRule ^en/dalmaturist$ /dalmaturist.php
RewriteRule ^en/payment$ /placanja.php
RewriteRule ^en/terms$ /uvjeti.php
RewriteRule ^en/accommodation/(.*)$ /smjestaj.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^en/smjestaj_sortiranje$ /smjestaj_sortiranje.php
RewriteRule ^en/object/(.*)/(.*)$ /smjestaj-objekt.php?SmjestajID=$1&SmjestajSeo=$2
RewriteRule ^en/rent-boat/(.*)$ /rent-boat.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^en/rent-boat_sortiranje$ /rent-boat_sortiranje.php
RewriteRule ^en/boat/(.*)/(.*)$ /rent-boat-objekt.php?PloviloID=$1&PloviloSeo=$2
RewriteRule ^en/excursions$ /izleti.php
RewriteRule ^en/souvenir-shop$ /suvenirnica.php
RewriteRule ^en/pakostane$ /pakostane.php
RewriteRule ^en/surroundings$ /okruzenje.php
RewriteRule ^en/contact$ /kontakt.php
RewriteRule ^en/bike-scooter$ /bike-scooter.php
RewriteRule ^en/reservation$ /rezervacija.php
RewriteRule ^en/thank-you$ /thank-you.php

## Njemački ##

RewriteRule ^de/dalmaturist$ /dalmaturist.php
RewriteRule ^de/wie-bezahlen$ /placanja.php
RewriteRule ^de/allgemeine-geschaftsbedingungen$ /uvjeti.php
RewriteRule ^de/unterkunft/(.*)$ /smjestaj.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^de/smjestaj_sortiranje$ /smjestaj_sortiranje.php
RewriteRule ^de/objekt/(.*)/(.*)$ /smjestaj-objekt.php?SmjestajID=$1&SmjestajSeo=$2
RewriteRule ^de/bootscharter/(.*)$ /rent-boat.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^de/rent-boat_sortiranje$ /rent-boat_sortiranje.php
RewriteRule ^de/boot/(.*)/(.*)$ /rent-boat-objekt.php?PloviloID=$1&PloviloSeo=$2
RewriteRule ^de/ausfluge$ /izleti.php
RewriteRule ^de/geschenkboutique$ /suvenirnica.php
RewriteRule ^de/pakostane$ /pakostane.php
RewriteRule ^de/umgebung$ /okruzenje.php
RewriteRule ^de/kontakt$ /kontakt.php
RewriteRule ^de/fahrrad-motorroller$ /bike-scooter.php
RewriteRule ^de/reservierung$ /rezervacija.php
RewriteRule ^de/thank-you$ /thank-you.php

ErrorDocument 401 http://www.dalmaturist.hr/
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.dalmaturist.hr/
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.dalmaturist.hr/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match query string in `Redirect` directive. Use `mod_rewrite` rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mjesto=1$
RewriteRule ^itravel/hrv/rezultati\.asp$ http://www.dalmaturist.hr/hr/smjestaj/? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^hrv/o_nama/index\.asp$ /hr/rent-boat/ [L,R=301]
```

And make sure this is placed right at top **before other rewrite rules**

Comment: `RewriteRule ^hrv/o_nama/index.asp /hr/najam-plovila/2 [L,R=301]` I manage to set up all link but this. index.asp is static site but /hr/najam-plovila/2 is pagination site. `RewriteRule ^hr/najam-plovila/(.*)$ /rent-boat.php?page=$1` Any idea how to set up that?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your comment.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^hrv/o_nama/index.asp /hr/najam-plovila/2 [L,R=301]` didn't work, I think that is because /hr/najam-plovila/2 is site with pagination, second page, maybe because of that?

Comment: But as per above rule you already have `^hrv/o_nama/index.asp$` going to `/hr/rent-boat/`

Comment: Here I update code in question. So you can look again.

Comment: as per edited code you are doing: `RewriteRule ^hrv/o_nama/index.asp /hr/najam-plovila/ [L,R=301]` and then you have `RewriteRule ^hr/najam-plovila/(.*)$ /rent-boat.php?page=$1` can you tell me in detail what is the problem?

Comment: all redirect work exept `RewriteRule ^hrv/o_nama/index.asp /hr/najam-plovila/ [L,R=301]`other 8 redirections work normaly after I edited like you suggested.

Comment: When I opened `http://www.dalmaturist.hr/hrv/o_nama/index.asp` it got redirected to `http://www.dalmaturist.hr/hr/najam-plovila/`

Comment: When I go online with another provider it works! Sorry, my bad!